# Entries in django admin panel is not clickable

Tags: python, django

[image]

I am making a django admin based project but  due to this error i am unable to proceed.

my code is

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
    from account.models import Account
    from import_export import resources
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin


        class AccounttResource(resources.ModelResource):
            class Meta:
                model=Account
                import_id_fields = ['cust_id']


        class AccountAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):

            resource_class = AccounttResource
            list_display = ['cust_first_name',]
            readonly_fields=('image_tag_thumb','image_tag','cust_id',)


        admin.site.register(Account,AccountAdmin)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
    from datetime import date
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.shortcuts import render ,redirect
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
    from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
    from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminFileWidget




# Create your models here.
class Account(models.Model):
    cust_id=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    cust_first_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cust_middle_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    cust_last_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    father_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    village_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    crusher_choices=(
        ('1','12X14'),
        ('2','13X15'),
        ('3','13X16'),
        ('4','14X16'),
        ('5','14X17'),
        ('6','15X17'),
        ('7','15X18'),
        ('8','16X17'),
        ('9','16X18'),
        ('10','17X18'),


        )
    size_of_crusher=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=crusher_choices,blank=True, null=True)
    bowl_choices=(
        ('1','62'),
        ('2','68'),
        ('3','72'),
        ('4','74'),


        )

    size_of_bowl=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=bowl_choices,blank=True, null=True)
    rent_fixed=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reffered_by=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    contact_no1=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    contact_no2=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    assigned_technician=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    first_deposit=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    date_of_rent=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    total_payment_received=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    balance=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0,blank=True, null=True)
    # item_replaced=
    technician_visit=models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    technician_name=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True)
    terms_and_condition=models.TextField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
    thumb_impression=models.ImageField(_('cust_thumb'), upload_to='photos/')
    cust_pic=models.ImageField(_('cust_image'), upload_to='photos/')




    def __str__(self):
        return self.cust_first_name


    def image_tag_thumb(self):

        return u'<img src="%s" width=100 height=120 />' % (self.thumb_impression.url)
    image_tag_thumb.short_description = 'Customer Image'
    image_tag_thumb.allow_tags = True

    def image_tag(self):

        return u'<img src="%s" width=100 height=120 />' % (self.cust_pic.url)
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'
    image_tag.allow_tags = True
    def save(self):
        a=int(self.total_payment_received)
        b=int(self.rent_fixed)
        self.balance=b-a
        super(Account,self).save()


        if(self.cust_id==None):

            print "inside cust id loop"
            queryset=Account.objects.all()

            data=request.POST

            temp=queryset.aggregate(Max('cust_id'))
            print temp
            temp=temp.get('cust_id__max')
            print "temp>>",temp

            cust_id=""
            if not temp :
                print"before"
                cust_id="CUST0001"
                print "cust_id=",cust_id
            else:
                print"after"
                print "m=",temp
                prefix=temp[0:4]
                print "prefix",prefix

                suffix=temp[4:]
                print "suffix",suffix

                int_suffix=int(suffix)  

                print "prefix=",prefix,"suffix=",suffix,"int_suffix",int_suffix
                if int_suffix<9 :
                    suffix="000"+str(int_suffix+1)
                elif int_suffix>=9 and int_suffix<99:
                    suffix="00"+str(int_suffix+1)
                elif int_suffix>=99 and int_suffix<999:
                    suffix="0"+str(int_suffix+1)
                elif int_suffix>=999 and int_suffix<9999:
                    suffix=""+str(int_suffix+1)


                cust_id=prefix+suffix
                print "cust_id=",cust_id

            account=Account()

            account.cust_id=cust_id
            account.cust_first_name=data.get('cust_first_name')
            account.cust=data.get('cust_address')
            account.is_active=data.get('is_active',default=False)

            if account.save():

                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response( status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


        else:
            pass

        print "cust_id",self.cust_id
```

now when i start this project and add new account.it is saved but account name is not clickable.and if again i create other account it replaces the last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class AccountAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = AccounttResource
    list_display = ['cust_first_name',]
    list_display_links = ('cust_first_name',)
    readonly_fields = ('image_tag_thumb', 'image_tag', 'cust_id',)
```

Comment: i have done this but my problem is not solved.please help me

Comment: cust_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create 2 accounts with identical primary key (cust_id), so on creating new one, make sure that you're entering new, non-empty key.

If you can't click that entry, make sure that you have proper permissions, you're not overwriting `has_change_permission` with something that will prevent you from editing that model. Also make sure that you're not setting `list_display_links` to `None`, empty list or some field that is not in `list_display` or simply does not exist in your model. You can try specifying `list_display_links` to list of fields that will link to edit form.

Comment: i have removed AccountResource class from admin and also save method for cust id...but the problem is remain.what should actually i do in my code.where is the problem in my code.iin admin.py or or in models.py

Comment: Main problem is with your `primary_key`. Do you really need separate field for that, without auto-increment and with  no way to edit it in your admin? If that field is empty, admin can't build URL to your object and if you will try to create another object with blank id, it will overwrite existing one.